# Grouping and pivoting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Names         Company    Values   Period
HeadCount     Google     1000     1
HoursWorked   Google     500      1
HeadCount     Microsoft  600      1
HoursWorked   Microsoft  200      1
HeadCount     Google     2000     2
HoursWorked   Google     100      2
```

I'd like to transform this dataframe to something like this:

```
Company   Period  HeadCount  HoursWorked
Google    1       1000       500
Google    2       2000       100
Microsoft 1       600        200
```

Is there a way to take the columns pivot them, but also group by the company period and have a dataframe that looks like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index=['Company', 'Period'], columns='Names', values='Values') \
      .rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()

     Company  Period  HeadCount  HoursWorked
0     Google       1       1000          500
1     Google       2       2000          100
2  Microsoft       1        600          200
```

**Edit**:

> I'm getting this error: all arrays must be same length

Solution: replace `pivot` by `pivot_table`.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `all arrays must be same length`

Comment: Is it possible to create a sample with the error?

Comment: Try to do just `df.pivot`. Is the error still there?

Comment: I just changed it to `pivot_table` and it worked

Comment: Strange but ok. I did not manage to reproduce the error. I updated my answer (if you want to accept it)